# find the last day/date of a WEEKOFYEAR with php

Tags: php, mysql, date, mktime

I have a value that is the number for the weekofyear (between 1-52 ). I want to find out the date (yyyy-mm-dd) for the last day of that week.

I would prefer to do it in PHP rathe then MYSQL.

Comment: Please remove the mysql tag if you want an answer in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily solved with [`DateTime::setISODate()`](http://php.net/manual/datetime.setisodate.php) method:

```php
$week = 50;

$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setISODate($dt->format('o'), $week, 7);

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/95108)</kbd>

Or you can just create `DateTime` object (or unix timestamp with `strtotime()`) with [ISO-8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) like `2014-W50-7`:

```php
$week = 50;
$iso = sprintf("2014-W%02d-7", $week);

$dt = new DateTime($iso);
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($iso)); # or using strtotime()
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/95115)</kbd>

Comment: Cheers Glavić, that does the trick perfectly! ;)